# Reminders deletes personal keychains in Catalina

Tags: keychain, catalina, reminders

Every time Catalina starts after booting, this message concerning my personal keychains (not system or session) pops up:
￼
[image]

When I click the CANCEL button, all passwords that are not private notes are deleted from the keychain. The message pops up as many times as items in the keychain.
Keychain files are altered, impossible to retrieve lost entries. I precise that no keychain is synchronized at all with iCloud. They are personal keychains for personal information only, no link with the session or the system.

Does any one encounter the same problem?

***New edition on february 2020***:

Catalina 10.15.3 has just been released but does not fix the bug.

Despite numerous threads on the forums dealing with this problem, Apple is doing nothing. I received no response despite several emails to Apple Technical and Feedback Services.

**PAY ATTENTION APPLE : Erasing secure and protected data by an unauthorized application is a very serious problem. This is more than a security breach, it is a system attack that erases sensitive user data in violation of data protection laws.**

***New edition on 2020 march 27***:

Good news, since the Catalina 10.15.4 update, the attack on keychains by the Reminders application seems to have stopped. However, it is advisable to remain cautious because unfortunately neither the problem nor its solution have been officially recognized by Apple.